# Validation of multiple response codes

Tags: citrus-framework

I have to use a REST api that creates a user. This api returns response code 201 (accepted), 409 (user already exists) or some other code in case something went wrong. I want to validate that the received response code is either 201 or 409 (and not something else).

Now my code only checks one of these response codes:

```
http()
      .client(AddUserClient)
      .receive()
      .response(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
```

Is it possible to change this, so both values results in an OK-test?

Cheers,
Ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Citrus Http Java fluent API does not support this kind of validation at the moment. I will add this as soon as possible, thanks for the hint!

In the meantime you will need to use the default receive fluent API for this special operation:

```
receive(AddUserClient)
    .payload(...)
    .header(HttpMessageHeaders.HTTP_STATUS_CODE, "@assertThat(anyOf(is(200), is(409)))@")    
    .header(HttpMessageHeaders.HTTP_VERSION, "HTTP/1.1");
```

You can combine Http fluent API and default fluent API in a Citrus test case without limitations.